# Auto populate polygon area in attribute form for QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

I am creating a form for QField use. I have created a polygon mapping layer as part of the form. In the polygon layer I have a field called "area". I just need to know how to configure the field setting so that when I map a polygon in the field (or on desktop) the "area" field is auto populated with the surface area measurement. I am using GDA94 Z55.

Answer (score 4):

- In QGIS, double-click your polygon layer to open the Layer
  Properties.
- Select the 'Attributes Form' menu from the left-hand
  side.
- At the top, change to the 'Drag and Drop Designer'. Drag all
  of the attributes that you want a user to see when they add a feature
  (polygon). Drag them from Available Widgets/Fields to Form Layout.
- Under the Form Layout column, select your "Area" attribute.
- Find the 'Default' menu on the right-hand side.  Set the Default value to
  $area . Tick the 'Apply default value on update'. Click Apply.

Now when you add an attribute, the area in sq.m. will be calculated. IF you wanted this in a different unit, then type in the math in Default Value. Example: hectares. 10,000 sq.m. = 1 ha. So, $area/10000 would calculate the area in ha.

You can design other options in this Drag and Drop Designer like setting a value to Required or set a range of numbers. This is also where you need to set the attribute to attachment to attach a photo from QField.

[image: Layer Properties Panel/Attribute Form / Drag and Drop Designer]